# Dynamic java from XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jelly

I would like to build some kind of object generation engine for my domain objects.
For example, lets assume, I'm working with graphs. The models are represented by xml and I should be able to load them and build a java representation at runtime.

Lets say, graph has vertices and edges
So it will look like this:

```
<graph>
   <vertex id="n1" color="red", thickness="2">
   <vertex id="n2">
   <edge end1="${n1}", end2="${n2}"/>
</graph>
```

For this I would like to get the objects that can be described by the following java classes:

```
class Graph {
     List<Vertex> vertexList
     List<Edge> edgeList
}

class Vertex {
   String id
    ... various properties ... 
}

class Edge {
   Vertex end1
   Vertex end2
}
```

Another requirement is to be able to define vertices in loop like this:

```
<graph>
  ...
    <for var = i, min = 1, max = 10, step = 1>
      <vertex id=$i.../> 
    </for>
  ... 
</graph>
```

I thought about using Apache Jelly but it seems to be a 'dead' project, JaxB doesn't allow such a level of dynamic behavior AFAIK...

My question is - what framework can you recommend for implementing such a task?

If there is something that works like Apache Jelly but still maintained, it could be great also :)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: why would you ever need to generate an "xml" for loop?

Comment: JSTL comes to mind, for example. The real task is to provide a convenient way of generating set of resources (for example, I would like to generate a graph with 1000 vertexes for testing purposes). So I would like to define a graph in a declarative manner.

Comment: There isn't really a question here. Your requirements can be interpreted as a DSL (domain-specific language) encoded in XML.  It's up to you to flesh out the DSL (the for-loop might be part of it), then write some Java code that reads and interprets the XML as appropriate.  This would be simple using a SAXParser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations can easily handle references within a document using a combination of `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF`.  I will demonstrate below with an example.

**JAVA MODEL**

**Graph**

```
package forum13404583;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Graph {

    @XmlElement(name = "vertex")
    List<Vertex> vertexList;

    @XmlElement(name = "edge")
    List<Edge> edgeList;

}
```

**Vertex**

In the `Vertex` class you need to use the `@XmlID` annotation to indicate that the `id` field is the id.

```
package forum13404583;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Vertex {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    String color;

    @XmlAttribute
    Integer thickness;

}
```

**Edge**

In the `Edge` class the `@XmlIDREF` annotation is used to indicate that the XML value contains  a foreign key that references the real value.

```
package forum13404583;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Edge {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlIDREF
    Vertex end1;

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlIDREF
    Vertex end2;

}
```

**DEMO CODE**

```
package forum13404583;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Graph.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum13404583/input.xml");
        Graph graph = (Graph) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(graph, System.out);
    }

}
```

**INPUT (input.xml)/OUTPUT**

Below is the input to and output from running the demo code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<graph>
    <vertex id="n1" color="red" thickness="2"/>
    <vertex id="n2"/>
    <edge end1="n1" end2="n2"/>
</graph>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, Blaise! I've completely missed this feature of JaXB.